# Keep context location change with DatagridView scroll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, contextmenustrip

I have a datagrid View and code is

```
 DataGridView m_ClientProcessDataGridView = new DataGridView();
```

And I have a context menu and it is

```
 ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStripForCells;
```

on right click on datagrid and showing context menu as

```
contextMenuStripForCells.Show(m_ClientProcessDataGridView.PointToScreen(e.Location));
```

The issue is when I scroll datagridview context menu will not move with row position, do we have any idea to keep it move with scroll?

Or can I disable datagridview scroll when context is open ?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish with *moving the context menu with the row position*? I ask because **1)** Logic to move the context menu may be difficult as scrolling gets large, **2)** Disabling the scroll is typically done with `dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;` which will refocus the grid back to the top (undesired perhaps), and **3)** What you are actually wanting may be better done another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll by wheel happens in `OnMouseWheel`. You can override the method and check if the `ContextMenuStrip` is open, prevent scroll:

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ContextMenuStrip != null && this.ContextMenuStrip.Visible)
            return;
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```